# Component with function child yields error "Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Consider the following react code: ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-gmv51c?file=/src/App.tsx))

```
import type { ReactNode } from 'react';

type RenderCallbackProps = {
  children: (o: { a: number }) => ReactNode,
};

function RenderCallback({ children }: RenderCallbackProps) {
  return (children({ a: 123 }));
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <RenderCallback>
      {({ a }) => (
        <h1>{a}</h1>
      )}
    </RenderCallback>
  );
}
```

This causes the error message:

```
function RenderCallback({ children }: RenderCallbackProps): ReactNode
'RenderCallback' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.ts(2786)
```

Why?

Where is the `undefined` coming from?

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is the `undefined` coming from?

That's part of what `ReactNode` means. `ReactNode` is: `ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined`, or basically all of the stuff that you could legally put as the child of a `<div>`. But while you can put a `undefined` as a child of a div, it can't be the only thing returned by a component, so you get an error when you try to do `return (children({ a: 123 }));`

You can fix this one of two ways. If you want to continue to allow null/undefined/boolean etc to be passed in, then just make sure that RenderCallback always wraps it in an element. A fragment will be enough:

```
function RenderCallback({ children }: RenderCallbackProps) {
  return (
    <>
      {children({ a: 123 })}
    </>
  )
}
```

Or if you don't want to allow those values, then you can change the types on the callback. For example only allowing elements:

```
children: (o: { a: number }) => ReactElement,
```

Comment: What an incredibly good answer. Thanks!!